# Django - Custom Login Page on index

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-login

I'm using Django and I'm creating an backend web application. Is it possible to create the URLs and functions for the login page but on index?

Without using default Django auth framework for authentication/login. I'm just about to write the function for this, but I have got no idea if it will work. I have also looked at other tutorials but I do tend to find these are out of date.

What I want is once the application loads, the user is prompted with a login box, once they login their details, then they are re-directed to the custom dashboard area (without using the built in Django).

**Urls.py File**

```
path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

**Views.py File**

```
@login_required
def index(request, user):
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user, 'index.html')

return HttpResponseRedirect ('dashboard.html')
```

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean by "login page but on index"? Maybe provide some example of desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I wanted to know if it was possible to overwrite the custom Django 'accounts/login' part. It is possible, but alot of tweaking is needed and making sure that everythings correct.

I can only hope that this helps others in the future.

## Urls.py

```
path('', LoginView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name="login"),
```

## Views.py

```
@login_required
def index(request):
return render(request, 'index.html')   

def login(request):
username = request.POST.get('username', '')
password = request.POST.get('password', '')
user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None and user.is_active:
    # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
    auth.login(request, user)
    # Redirect to a success page.
return render(request, 'admin/dashboard.html')  

def dashboard(request):
return render(request, 'admin/dashboard.html')
```

## Settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/dashboard'
```

I still have a few more features to implement but I hope this helps others.